# how to download email attachment with selenium python?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, html-email

This is the html for the download part of the page:

```html
<ul id="attachment-list" class="attachmentslist"><li class="application vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet xlsx" id="attach2"><a href="./?_task=mail&amp;_action=get&amp;_mbox=INBOX&amp;_uid=1&amp;_token=ukxOEh6bQm6Iv7gN59mROEbGpTrczta3&amp;_part=2" onclick="return rcmail.command('load-attachment','2',this)" onmouseover="rcube_webmail.long_subject_title_ex(this, 0)" title="" class="filename"><span class="attachment-name">2ART.xlsx</span><span class="attachment-size">(~740 KB)</span></a><a href="#" tabindex="0" title="Opções" class="button icon dropdown skip-content"><span class="inner">Opções</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

and I can't find any element related to the file.

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="attach2"]/a[2]')
```

the output is:

> Message: no such element: Unable to locate element:
> {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="attach2"]/a[2]"}

Comment: Your xpath selection gives me output: "Opções" . You need more clearify your question or you can represent your full code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check in the `dev tools` (Google chrome) if we have **unique** entry in `HTML-DOM` or not.

xpath that you should check :

```
//ul[@id='attachment-list']//li[@id='attach2']//a[@title='Opções']
```

**Steps to check:**

`Press F12 in Chrome` -> go to `element` section -> do a `CTRL  + F` -> then paste the `xpath` and see, if your desired `element` is getting **highlighted** with `1/1` matching node.

If it's a unique match then click it like below:

**Code trial 1:**

```
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//ul[@id='attachment-list']//li[@id='attach2']//a[@title='Opções']").click()
```

**Code trial 2:**

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//ul[@id='attachment-list']//li[@id='attach2']//a[@title='Opções']"))).click()
```

**Imports:**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Code trial 2 is recommended.

if you still face the `NoSuchElementException:` with code trial 1 then debug like this:

If this is unique `//ul[@id='attachment-list']//li[@id='attach2']//a[@title='Opções']` then you need to check for the below conditions as well.

1. Check if it's in any `iframe/frame/frameset`.

   **Solution:** switch to iframe/frame/frameset first and then interact with this web element.
2. Check if it's in any `shadow-root`.

   **Solution:** Use `driver.execute_script('return document.querySelector` to have returned a web element and then operates accordingly.
3. If you have redirected to a `new tab/ or new windows` and you have not **switched** to that particular `new tab/new window`, otherwise you will likely get `NoSuchElement` exception.

   **Solution:** switch to the relevant window/tab first.
4. If you have switched to an iframe and the new desired element is not in the same iframe context then first `switch to default content` and then interact with it.

   **Solution:** switch to default content and then switch to respective iframe.

Comment: Thanks!! I needed to switch the frame

Comment: @CarolVieira: yw!